# Android Editext: Layout with 2 Edit Text fields needs 2 click to clear the text?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have 2 edit text fiels on the layout name MainActivity.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt1"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt2"/>
```

I want to clear the text when I click on the text field.
In case I have **1 text field**, when I click on it, the text will be clear immediately.

However, in my situation (2 text fields), when I enter text for field 1, then field 2.

Then click to field 1 again, and it need 2 clicks to clear the text.

I guess the problem related to **Focusable**

Java code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    edt1.setOnClickListener(this);

    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    edt2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.edt1:
            edt1.setText("");
            break;
        case R.id.edt2:
            edt2.setText("");
            break;

    }

}
```

Any one can help my? I really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to clear you text on user click, maybe you are looking for the hint property of a edittext. btw, did you try the `onFocusChangeListener()` ?

Comment: Is this bit of code right? `case R.id.edt2: edt1.setText("");` Shouldn't it be be case `R.id.edt2: edt2.setText("");` Or maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `focusChnagedListener` on `EdiText`

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
       // clear the text
    }
   }
});
```